# Call a method from a service into a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this service structure:

```
export default class ChartDataService {
    constructor($http, authService) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.authService = authService;
    }
     getData(dataa) {       

      //do something

}

ChartDataService.$inject = ['$http', 'authService'];
```

And the controller structure:

```
class DemandCtrl {
    constructor(ChartDataService) {
        this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;
        this.dataa = {
            from: '10/01/2017',
            to:  '10/03/2017'
        };
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);       
    }

    update() {
        console.log('show something');
        DemandCtrl.ChartDataService.getData(this.dataa);        
    }
}
...
DemandCtrl.$inject = ['ChartDataService'];

export const Demand = {
    bindings: {
        data: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: demandPageHtml,
    controller: DemandCtrl
};
```

I want to call in `update()` the `getData()` function from the service. No matter how I try, `getData()`, `ChartDataService.getData(this.dataa)` or `DemandCtrl.ChartDataService.getData(this.dataa)`, I get the same error: **it is undefined.**

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you registering it as a service somewhere, as [stated on the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#registering-services)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is by using `.call()` like in the `$onInit()`.

In this particular case, the content of `update()` must be:

```
update() {
        getData.call(null, this);       
    }
```